# Gnome 3.8 on Fedora 19 error with windows Bar

Tags: gnome

Sorry about my English skill. Currently, I am using Gnome 3 On the Fedora 19. (Sometime I switch to Cinnamon desktop :)). When I using Gnome 3, the window top bar is not uniform on all windows, but on Cinnamon, that is working well. If you know about that, pls tell me why and how to fix it!!! Thanks to much...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt2i5.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZK4c.png

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when install almost every theme on Fedora 19, Nautilus fails to respect gnome's theme settings. After some research, my best guess about why it happens is because most themes only support nautilus 3.6 but however in fedora 19 we have nautilus 3.8. And there is no way to downgrade.
(I also tried your theme from http://satya164.deviantart.com/art/Numix-GTK3-theme-360223962 and with no luck, it doesn't work for me either. I'll update if I find a way)